# When i am writing letters it prints me Segmentation fault (core dumped) and many times of something

Tags: c

sorry for bothering you , i know that here's a lot of questions similar to mine , but i really don't understand, i am new in this language , thank you for understanding , and sorry again.
here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int year , month;

    printf("Which year? : ");
    scanf("%i",&year);
    
    if ( year < 0 )
    {
        printf("Wrong input for year , try again !\n");
        return main();
    }

    printf("Whcih month? : (1-12) ");
    scanf("%i",&month);

    if ( month < 1 || month > 12 )
    {
        printf("Wrong input for month , try again !\n");
        return main();
    }

    if ( month == 1 )
    {
        printf("In January 31 days\n");
    }
    
    else if ( month == 2 )
    {
        if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0 )) || (year % 400 == 0))
        {
            printf("In February 29 days ( this year is leap )\n");
        }
        
        else
        {
            printf("In February 28 days ( common year )\n");
        }
        
    }
    
    else if ( month == 3 )
    {
        printf("In March 31 days\n");
    }
    
    else if ( month == 4 )
    {
        printf("In April 30 days\n");
    }
    
    else if ( month == 5 )
    {
        printf("In May 31 days\n");
    }
    
    else if ( month == 6 )
        {
                printf("In June 30 days\n");
        }
    
    else if ( month == 7 )
        {
                printf("In July 31 days\n");
        }
    
    else if ( month == 8 )
        {
                printf("In August 31 days\n");
        }
    
    else if ( month == 9 )
        {
                printf("In September 30 days\n");
        }
    
    else if ( month == 10 )
        {
                printf("In October 31 days\n");
        }
    
    else if ( month == 11 )
        {
                printf("In November 30 days\n");
        }
    
    else if ( month == 12 )
        {
                printf("In December 31 days\n");
        }

}
```

when I input letter I want for to program return to main . but it prints many times of "Which year? : Which month? : (1-12) Wrong input for month , try again !" and "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" why ?

Comment: `scanf` does not consume the input if it does not match the specifier. So when you enter the letter `scanf` will keep failing and leave the letter in the input buffer. Don't use `scanf` for this. Use `fgets` to consume the input and then use another function such as `sscanf` to parse the input.

Comment: Also, whilst it is technically ok to call `main` recursively is is better practice to write a seperate function to be called from `main`.

Comment: Recursively calling main() is an inappropriate way to handle input errors:(

Comment: @kaylum First of all thank you very much for answering to my question , i really understand that i have to sscanf and fgets , but how i said before i am new in this language ... , i haven't learned in university yet , so i really don't understand . how i should do it , yes i know that i can look for it in internet and etc.. but sorry me , i have less time to submit my work , i will REALLY GRATEFUL , if you show how exactly should i replace scanf by sscanf and fgets in my code , sorry again i know it is not your responsible , but anyway i will know it better in future , thank you 4 ur understan

Comment: You should read about loops to ask again and again. But without fixing the `scanf` error as Kaylum wrote (and please note: You should replace `scanf` with `fgets`. You should not use both together), this will not help. Actually you do not return to `main` but you call another instance of `main`. That is called recursion and consumes your stack memory.

Comment: Omg it so complicated right now for me , aghh , anyway , i will submit my code without any changes , i don't think this will be taken into account in my grades , since we have not passed it yet , anyway thank you of all your responses .

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop which will repeat and ask for a value again, when the user input is wrong. You can use a "do-while" loop which will ask the input while the user submits it wrong. Try this code below, which checks in the input of month and year, if there is a letter or a false number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int year , month, res;
    //checks years
    printf("Which year? : ");
    do {
        res = scanf("%d", &year);
        if (res != 1) {
            printf("Error reading number, try again:\n");
            while (getchar() != '\n') {
                continue;
            }
            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }while (1);
    if (year < 0){
        do{
            printf("Year must be positive, Try again: ");
            do{
                res = scanf("%d", &year);
                if (res != 1) {
                printf("Error reading number, try again:\n");
                while (getchar() != '\n') {
                    continue;
                }
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }while(1);
        }while(year < 0);
    }

    printf("Which month? : (1-12) ");
    //checks months
    do {
        res = scanf("%d", &month);
        if (res != 1) {
            printf("Error reading number, try again:\n");
            while (getchar() != '\n') {
                continue;
            }
            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }while (1);
    if (month < 1 || month > 12){
        do{
            printf("Year must be positive, Try again: ");
            do{
                res = scanf("%d", &month);
                if (res != 1) {
                printf("Error reading number, try again:\n");
                while (getchar() != '\n') {
                    continue;
                }
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }while(1);
        }while(month < 1 || month > 12);
    }

    if ( month == 1 )
    {
        printf("In January 31 days\n");
    }

    else if ( month == 2 )
    {
        if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0 )) || (year % 400 == 0))
        {
            printf("In February 29 days ( this year is leap )\n");
        }

        else
        {
            printf("In February 28 days ( common year )\n");
        }

    }

    else if ( month == 3 )
    {
        printf("In March 31 days\n");
    }

    else if ( month == 4 )
    {
        printf("In April 30 days\n");
    }

    else if ( month == 5 )
    {
        printf("In May 31 days\n");
    }

    else if ( month == 6 )
        {
                printf("In June 30 days\n");
        }

    else if ( month == 7 )
        {
                printf("In July 31 days\n");
        }

    else if ( month == 8 )
        {
                printf("In August 31 days\n");
        }

    else if ( month == 9 )
        {
                printf("In September 30 days\n");
        }

    else if ( month == 10 )
        {
                printf("In October 31 days\n");
        }

    else if ( month == 11 )
        {
                printf("In November 30 days\n");
        }

    else if ( month == 12 )
        {
                printf("In December 31 days\n");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your effort is appreeciated. Nevertheless you might want to read the very first comment under the question. Your solution avoids endless recursion and the core dump but will still fail to continue if a letter was entered.

Comment: I will check it out, thank you for your time

Comment: That's a bit more complicated than IT needs to be but should work. You don't need any of those continue s at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `scanf` to get an integer but the user enters a letter, this letter will not be removed from the input. The result is that another call to `scanf` to get an integer will fail in the same way.

To solve that problem, use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.
`fgets` will consume the whole line from input and in case of an error you can request new input from user.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main()
{
    int year = -1, month = 0;
    char buf[50];

    while (year < 0)
    { 
        printf("Which year? : ");        
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL)
        {
           char *endptr=buf;
           long result = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);

           if ((result == 0 && errno == EINVAL)  // detect error
             || result < 0)                      // check range as in original question
               printf("Wrong input for year, try again !\n");
           else
               year = (int)result;
        }
    }
 // Same for month...
```

This solution also avoids calling `main` recursively which is not strictly forbidden but I would clearly call it bad practice. There is no need for recursion.
It also has the drawback that in case of a wrong value for month the user will also e prompted for the year again.